# Kde Neon/Ubuntu 18.04 Nvidia driver for Geforce 1650, MSI Prestige 15 A10SC

Tags: ubuntu, kde, nvidia

I have an issue installing nvidia driver on my MSI Prestige A10SC on KDE Neon (based on ubuntu 18.04)

I had to install the hwe kernel in order to have the wifi working, using the following command:

```
$ sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

Now I have this kernel:

```
$ uname -r
5.3.0-24-generic
```

I have disabled secure boot

```
$ mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot disabled
```

My card is detected in ubuntu:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001F91sv00001462sd0000129Cbc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

I tried to install nvidia driver doing this:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-435
```

After reboot I have this:

```
$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver.
Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

$ prime-select query
nvidia

$ nvidia-settings

ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).


ERROR: Error querying connected displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).

** Message: 10:51:29.107: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 10:51:29.107: PRIME: is it supported? no

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should have been installed
       along with this driver at /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation.
       The application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be prepopulated or
       validated, and will not be listed in the help text. Please see the README for possible
       values and descriptions.
```

I don't know what to do now and I do not find the so called readme in the last error message.

Thank you in advance, I am a little bit lost.